# FFMPEG when capturing an internet streaming, start time does not zero

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, timestamp, streaming

I am trying to capture an internet streaming in mp3, however the initial time does not start at zero, I can use -ss, but I would like to know if it is possible to start capturing from the moment I execute the command.

For example, if I try to capture 1 minute in real time from a stream, it starts with 47 seconds instead of 0 seconds

[Start time to capture stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bab96.png)

I need the start time being to zero, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Show the full log of this command with `-v 40` added.

Comment: Sorry, this is because I need to generate segments of certain exact time, however, some streaming starts with a time already loaded and when generating the cuts automatically, the time of each one can vary by that initial time that is loaded. I will review the suggested forums, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the next command before input source:

**ffmpeg -re -fflags + genpts -i INPUT**.... *commands and output*

And my segments start in the real time, without caché or buffer streaming.
Thanks for your support guys... !! :D